# Where can I get a cheap database, no web hosting needed

Tags: web-hosting, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm building an application which requires a fairly small online MySQL database.

I don't need any web hosting. What are some cheap options for an online database?

****Edit(a bit more about what I'll be using it for)***

*The database itself is very small it contains market statistics for 5 weeks of time. Once a week the data will be updated, so that it always contains the most recent 5 weeks.*

*Then I will use the data in that to create an XML file which is generated with PHP. The XML file will need to be accessed hundreds-thousands of times per month.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free Webhosting will also provide Free MYSQL database . So , You can use that service with out any problem as long as your  free webhoster offers you service.  you can try .

Comment: This sounds like a good option can you add some links.

Comment: @PhilipK  you can check this free hsoter its one of my fav free hoster   http://www.x10hosting.com/   or else  you can hceck this link which provide list of free hosting websites http://www.free-webhosts.com/free-mysql-database.php

Answer (score 1):

Google [MySQL hosting](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=MySQL%20hosting)... Most of the people who offer SQL only services also offer web hosting, and you may find the cheaper webhosts are less expensive than the SQL only offerings.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the best answer, it'd be great to know what kind of application we are dealing with. It's definitely cheap to pay for a regular, shared PHP+MySQL host, as long as you make sure excessive remote database usage doesn't violate their ToS.

I don't know what do you mean by "cheap" exactly, but if you are developing a commercial app, you should consider opting for some cloud or VPS service. Providers, such as Amazon AWS offer a fair price, and if you can afford it, it does a nice job. (If you have a low/moderate traffic, price of a database-cloud should be under 100 USD/Mo.) VPS is even cheaper.

Comment: I've posted a bit more about what I'll be using it for.

Comment: In this case, going with a shared webhosting (PHP+MySQL) is an easy and cheap option. Also, if you generate the XML once a week, you can cache it on the hosting service, reducing pressure on the database.